# Create a collapsible div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I am trying to create a collapsible div but chrome console says 'undefined is not a function' on line attr data role collapsible. Can you tell me how to do this:

```
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'sectorDiv_'+distritoPosicion;
iDiv.className = 'sectorDiv_'+distritoPosicion;
iDiv.attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
iDiv.attr('data-collapsed-icon', 'arrow-r');
iDiv.attr('data-expanded-icon', 'arrow-d');
document.getElementsById('listaSectores')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
```

distritoPosicion is a numberand listaSectores is an existing div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr()` is a method from jQuery, it's `setAttribute()` you are after.

```
iDiv.setAttribute('data-role', 'collapsible');
iDiv.setAttribute('data-collapsed-icon', 'arrow-r');
iDiv.setAttribute('data-expanded-icon', 'arrow-d');
```

Also you're trying to get your element the wrong way.

```
document.getElementsById('listaSectores')[0]
```

it's normally `getElementById` (no s at element) and it returns only one element so `[0]` is not needed in this case.

```
document.getElementById('listaSectores').appendChild(iDiv);
```

Comment: The first error he would get would be that there's no attr() function on dom elements.

Comment: You have to use setAttribute method: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp

Comment: True, missed that one :) I updated my answer, attr is more a jquery stuff that native.

Comment: You should probably reorder your answer so that it's explaining why `attr()` doesn't work, then give the side-note on `getElementsById()`.

Comment: yep was just doing that as you were posting it, makes a lot more sense that way.

Comment: Thanks. Now it add the content to a new div. But collapsible is not working yet.

Comment: No it wouldn't there is not java script to dynamically change the class name, now you need to work on that side.